# Facebook HackerCup 2013 BalancedSmileys Explanation

Tags: algorithm

My question is in reference to the FB HackerCup 2013 QualificationRound problem - BalancedSmileys.

Problem Statement: https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=403525256396727&round=185564241586420 (copy here too: https://github.com/anuragkapur/Algorithmic-Programming/tree/master/src/com/anuragkapur/fb/hackercup2013/qr#problem-2-balanced-smileys)

I figured how to solve this problem using the BruteForce method which has exponential running time.

As per the official solutions posted, there is a solution with linear running time. It is described here: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-hacker-cup/qualification-round-solutions/598486173500621

Essentially, it maintains two counters: minOpen and maxOpen. Whenever a open parenthesis "(" is encountered, maxOpen is incremented. If the "(" was NOT a part of a smiley, minOpen is also incremented. Similar strategy for handling ")" as well, as described in the explanation link above.

I can see that the linear time method works, but it is not crystal clear in my head - how? So I am polling this group to find out if anyone can give an alternate "explanation" of the linear running time solution.

Many thanks!

Comment: You have to have an equal amount of open and close brackets. You do not count the ones in smileys. There is nothing more to this

Comment: Just an equal amount of open and close brackets is not enough. They need to be in the right order. Also, I dont think it is true to say that the brackets in smileys are not counted. They are, if there isn't a simple bracket to balance another. Thats why minOpen and maxOpen are evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing: tokenize the input and convert each token to a list containing the possible effects on the open parenthesis count.

The inputs

```
i am sick today (:()
:(:))
```

become

```
[[0], [0], ..., [0], [1], [0, 1], [-1]]
[[0, 1], [-1, 0], [-1]]
```

. Now, your brute force algorithm is something like this.

```
def solution1(lst, opencnt=0, i=0):
    if opencnt < 0:
        return False
    elif i >= len(lst):
        return opencnt == 0
    else:
        for delta in lst[i]:
            if solution1(lst, opencnt + delta, i + 1):
                return True
        return False
```

The function `solution1` always gives the same output for a given input. For a given `lst` with entries in {-1, 0, 1}, there are only a linear number of possibilities for each of `opencnt` (-1 to `len(lst)`) and `i` (0 to `len(lst) - 1`), so by caching the output for a given input, namely, [memoizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), we get the quadratic-time algorithm.

The linear-time algorithm turns the control flow inside out. Instead of making a separate recursive call for each `delta`, we make `opencnt` a set.

```
def solution2(lst, opencnt={0}, i=0):
    opencnt = {x for x in opencnt if x >= 0}
    if i >= len(lst):
        return 0 in opencnt
    else:
        return solution2(lst, {x + delta for x in opencnt for delta in lst[i]}, i + 1)
```

This implementation isn't linear time yet. The final optimization is that `opencnt` is always an interval, i.e., [minOpen, maxOpen], and can be manipulated in constant time.

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the colon in rule #2, the obvious algorithm would be a finite state machine with two states, which loops over the string and maintains a parentheses count:

- `pcount = 0`
- for each character:

  - if it is ':': discard next character
  - if it is '(': `pcount++`
  - if it is ')': `pcount--` if `pcount > 0`, otherwise immediately return "NO"

The fact that rule #2 allows colons makes it a bit more challenging, since messages of the form "(:)" or, say, "(   foo   :)" may be regarded to have balanced parentheses as well. What this rule essentially says is that "you find it hard to tell if a parenthesis really is a parenthesis or part of an emoticon", and you shall determine whether "there is a way to interpret his message while leaving the parentheses balanced".

To put it more clearly: **We don't actually care for the emoticons at all.** We shall find out whether the parentheses may be balanced.

The naive approach is to maintain an array of parentheses counters. Initially, it contains only one parentheses counter. Each time you encounter '(' or ')', you append the current parentheses counter array to itself, in-/decrementing the first half as suggested in the simple algorithm above. Once you reach the end of the string, you check whether the array contains zeros. If it does, there's a way for the string to be regarded as having balanced parentheses. Otherwise, there's not.

There might be room for improvements to this 2nd algorithm, and there may even be a jaw-droppingly elegant solution that won't run out of memory if the message consists of 1000 parentheses. However, given enough RAM, this naive approach will determine the correct answer in linear time (and, sadly, exponential space).

Comment: Should have read your question more carefully. I'll leave my answer as a reminder for others.